# Unable to run the appcelerator titanium app in IOS8

Tags: android, xcode, ios8, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I am using the latest version of studio

`Titanium Studio, build: 3.4.0.201409261227,
Mac OS Version 10.9.5,
alloy version 1.5.1,
Titanium SDK version is 3.4.0.GA`

i want to update my app to IOS8, which was previously developed in IOS7 using titanium,
But i am unable to run, 
I am getting the following error

```
[ERROR] :  2014-10-07 10:14:04.018 xcodebuild[27236:5403]  DeveloperPortal: Using pre-existing     current store at URL (file:///Users/arunkumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DeveloperPortal%206.0.1.db).
[ERROR] :  ** BUILD FAILED **
[ERROR] :  The following build commands failed:
[ERROR] :   Ld build/Debug-iphonesimulator/My\ App.app/My\ App normal i386
[ERROR] :  (1 failure)'
```

I Had Also updated my xcode to latest version(6.0.1), i can run an empty project, but i am unable to find whats wrong with my app, Please help me to find the solution
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a Module Conflict.

- Try deleting modules one by one to identify the module in conflict.
- Update the module.
- If no updated module available for the Titanium SDK install previous version of SDK

**Details**

I've installed the Titanium Studio for the first time. Got exactly this error. Couldn't run it in iOS simulator. This is what I did.

- Deleting modules one by one and trying to run. I found that `analytics.google` module was the culprit. Tried to run with all the different versions. [see picture]
- Trying to install new version of `analytics.google`. For this, I needed to install `gitto`

  ```
  sudo npm install -g gittio
  ```

  then install `analytics.google`

  ```
  gittio install analytics.google
  ```

  found out there is `no distributable available`
- Install previous version of Titanium SDK. The previous app was build with 3.4.0. My SDK was 3.5.1GA. So I tried to install 3.4.0 with

  ```
  ti sdk install http://builds.appcelerator.com/mobile/3.4.0/mobilesdk-3.4.0.RC2-osx.zip
  ```

  Also you can install SDK from Titanium Studio help menu.

  ```
  Help >> Install Titanium SDK >> ...
  ```

  Then Select the 3.4.0 SDK in the Titanium SDK drop down [see pictue]

[image]